# Google Cloud Messaging iOS, receiving multiple notifications

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I've implemented [Google Cloud Messaging for iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/start?ver=swift) succesfully and I'm sending the following HTTP format from my server:

```
$jsonData = array(
    'to' => '/topics/' . $data['abbreviation'],
    'notification' => array(
        'body' => $data['body'],
        'title' => $data['title']
    )
);
```

The data is sent succesfully and the iOS application is showing the notification. Only it's showing it 2 to 5 times and I'm sure the server is only sending it once because I'm sending the same format to Android which only gets 1 notification instead of multiple.

Am I forgetting something? My AppDelegate is as following:

```
func application( application: UIApplication,
    didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
    fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // This works only if the app started the GCM service
    GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);

    handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData)
    // Invoke the completion handler passing the appropriate UIBackgroundFetchResult value
}
```

Does Google Cloud Messaging send the notification multiple times to the Apple APNS or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to occur after an uninstall.

Google recognized the bug on their side [github.com/google/gcm/issues/101](http://github.com/google/gcm/issues/101)